# Pythonanywhere Textract UnicodeDecodeError ONLY on website

Tags: python, pdf, flask, web, pythonanywhere

I am developing a website which should be able to take PDF files and extract 8 digit numbers from them ([Website link](https://jw30.pythonanywhere.com) + [GitHub repo](https://github.com/JW30/jw30pdf)).

However when trying to process this PDF file [AbenteuerGarten2021.pdf](https://easyupload.io/erfbhs) with the textract package I get the following [UnicodeDecodeError](https://codeshare.io/Wdd4bv) !

Strangely when running the exact same flask app on the development server with the exactly same PDF file mentioned above I don't get an error and it works perfectly.

I am using Python 3.8.2 on local environment (Big Sur 11.4) and 3.8.0 on pythonanywhere. Both environments use the following:

- Flask 2.0.1
- Werkzeug 2.0.1
- Textract 1.6.3

Please can anyone help me, I don't understand where the problem is coming from.

---

I managed to fix the problem by using the method "pdfminer" in process call. I have no idea why it works, but it does. For anyone having similar problem.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting encoding in `textract.process` call?

Comment: No, how would I do that and how would I find out which encoding to set?

Comment: From the documentation: `import textract; text = textract.process('path/to/file.extension', encoding='ascii')` (use utf-8 instead of ascii), https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python_package.html

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't work unfortunately.